# Read Variable from a Class

Tags: java, android, json

Hi after countless hours, I figured out what I really what my problem is but still cannot find an answer.

```
@Override
    public void onStampResult(StampResult result) {
    }
```

onStampResult returns a Class StampResult with the follwowing parameters:

```
public class StampResult implements Serializable {
  public SnowShoeError error;
  public SnowShoeStamp stamp;
  public boolean secure;
  public String receipt;
  public Date created;
}
```

SnowShoeStamp Class is:

```
public class SnowShoeStamp implements Serializable {
  public String serial;
}
```

And SnowShoeError Class is:

```
public class SnowShoeError implements Serializable {
  public int code;
  public String message;
}
```

In onStampResult I can write down logic depending on the output of `result`.
On Success ´stamp´ gets initialized and ´error´ does not exist.

On Error, `stamp` does not exist and `error` gets initialized.

The `result` gets parsed to from JSON to the Class in the following way:

```
try {
     stampResult = gson.fromJson(result, StampResult.class);
      } catch (JsonSyntaxException jsonException) {
        stampResult = new StampResult();
        stampResult.error = new SnowShoeError();
        stampResult.error.message = result;
        }
    mOnStampListener.onStampResult(stampResult);
    mStampBeingChecked = false;
 }
```

How do I test if either `error` or `stamp` exists without getting a NullPointerExeption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I misunderstood your question, you simply need to check for null.

In order to handle the different cases, you could do the following:

```
@Override
public void onStampResult(StampResult result) {
    if (result.error == null){
        SnowShoeStamp stamp = result.stamp;
        // Process stamp
    } else {
        SnowShoeError error = stampResult.error;
        // Process error
    }
}
```

Comment: I would hug you if I could! For you this was probably an easy answer, for me this was 10 hours of frustration.
Thank you!